# A cup product in etale cohomology of Elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-cohomology

Another related question was posted here

[A cup product in Galois cohomology of Elliptic curve](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254759/a-cup-product-in-galois-cohomology-of-elliptic-curve)

Prof. Silverman suggested me to post this in another thread so I post it here.

Suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with conductor $N$ and $p$ is a prime which does not divide N (that is E has good reduction at p.) Then, we can define the following pairing

$$ \phi: H_{et}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}[1/Np],E[p]) \times H_{et}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}[1/Np],E[p]) \to H_{et}^{2}(\mathbb{Z}[1/Np], \mu_p)$$

(one can equivalently define the above pairing as cup product of Galois cohomology of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_{\Sigma}/\mathbb{Q})$ with $\Sigma$ is the set of primes of $Np$).

Note that the right hand sight is not trivial as $H_{et}^{2}(\mathbb{Z}[1/Np], \mu_{p})=H_{et}^{2}(\mathbb{Z}[1/Np], \mathbb{G}_{m})[p]$ by Kummer theory and $H_{et}^{2}(\mathbb{Z}[1/Np],\mathbb{G}_{m})$ fits into the exact sequence

$$0 \to H_{et}^2(\mathbb{Z}[1/Np], \mathbb{G}_m) \to \bigoplus_{\ell| Np} Br(\mathbb{Q_{\ell}}) \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$$

As $N>1$, this middle term has corank at least $2$ so the first time has corank at least $1$.

My question: are there any known examples where the above map $\phi$ is non-trivial?

Comment: Do you work out what happens for $p=2$ and when $E$ has full two torsion? Here you can make everything explicit using Kummer theory.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I worked this out and it seems to work. In this case, the question is whether the cup product $H^{1}(R, \mu_{2}) \times H^{1}(R, \mu_2) \to H^2(R, \mu_2)$ is non-trivial. Here $R=Z[1/Np]$. We can put this one into a commutative square with the vertical map $H^1(R, \mu_2) \to H^1(Q, \mu_2)$ and $H^2(R, \mu_2) \to H^2(Q, \mu_2)=Br(Q)[2]$. The cup product of Galois cohomology can be interpreted as the Hilbert symbol. So, to check that the above pairing is non-trivial, one only needs to find $a,b \in R^{\times}$ such that $(a,b)_{v}$ is not zero for some $v | Np$.

Comment: For the original question, I actually believe (and hope) that the above pairing is non-trivial for all $p$ satisfying the good reduction hypothesis. I have no evidence for this statement; so I was afraid to say it publicly.